# DB Connection access timing

Tags: c#, database

I need to write a huge amount of data to a postgredb. The PG `connection_limit` is set to 200. And I need to write ~5000 values per second. If I open a new connection for every query, I get too many clients errors. But if I use only one connection, its to slow to insert ~5000 values.

What is the correct method to manage the connection in this case?

At the moment I open and close the connection for every query

```
public static async Task WriteValueAsync(Item Item)
{
    try
    {
        using (NpgsqlConnection con = new NpgsqlConnection(constring))
        {
             con.Open();
             String sql = "INSERT INTO \"" + Item.ID + "\" (...) VALUES (...)";
             NpgsqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
             cmd.CommandText = sql;
             await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
             cmd.Dispose();
             con.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("DB WriteValueAsync: " + e.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Keep open connection. Why it is slow to insert 5000 values? Maybe you have many indexes for that table.

Comment: Use `Stored Procedure` instead of hardcoded query in code, and pass your values to it as a parameter then you can do more to make it more efficient.

Comment: @i486
I create new table for this test, so they are empty and contains each 3 indexes. But I need these indexes for later use. I cannot remove them

Comment: @Mehmood  Now I use 'Stored Procedure' ;-)

Comment: 5000 values are not very much. What is the CPU and storage? Is it HDD or some USB Flash? Enable write cache for the HDD.

Comment: At the moment it's in a vm, with 3.60GHz and 4GB Ram on SSHD
The Database has 3.60GHz and 8GB Ram on SSHD.
For testing...

Comment: @i486 Now I open a new connection for every 5000 values. I resized the `connection_limit` to 1100 connections. Not it works fine :-)